# console not printing valueof(this) and cannot understand context of 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery, libraries

I cannot understand a few things regarding my code so far, I don't even know what to ask in general, but I'll start with the `console.log(valueof(this));` [line 37]  in the sense of why it doesn't print the value of the object 'test'. While this is not vital to the code, it will help me understand this much better as to who/what/where/when/why/how of 'this'.  I understand if this is a broad question, but I'm just so lost in this at this point, I'm trying to understand how jQuery and I'm sure plenty of other libraries add $ and their names to the namespace and bind them to the window object and how this and prototypes apply to that. I understand if you all rail me for this question, but please point me to some resources if at all possible.

```
(function (window, undefined) {
    //Variables for the Results container(resultsBox),
    // unordered list(resultsList).
    var resultsBox = document.createElement('div'),
        resultsList = document.createElement('ul'),
        resultEntry;
    //Add to HTML in proper place within page  
    document.body.appendChild(resultsBox).setAttribute('class', 'resultsBox');
    resultsBox.appendChild(resultsList).setAttribute('class', 'resultsList');
    //ResultBox Styles
    resultsBox.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)';
    resultsBox.style.minHeight = '1.5em';
    resultsBox.style.maxHeight = '6em';
    resultsBox.style.width = '10em';
    resultsBox.style.position = 'fixed';
    resultsBox.style.bottom = '0';
    resultsBox.style.right = '2em';

    //Library name : test
    var test = function () {
      for (var i = arguments.length; i < arguments[i]; i++) {
        if ( typeof(arguments[i]) === 'array' ) {
          createItem('Cannot Handle Array Items at this time')
        } else {
          this.checkBool();
          this.createItem();
        }
      }
      this.checkBool = function () {};
      this.createItem = function () {};
      console.log(window.valueOf(this));  ////this will not log?????? <--
      return test;
    };
    window.test = test;
}) (window)
```

Comment: You don't seem to be calling `test()` anywhere.

Comment: Why are you calling `window.valueOf()` (which will always return `window` despite of its arguments)?

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/8x450p85/. Have you actually called `test()` anywhere? Also note that `window.valueOf()` doesn't seem to be what you require, but just `console.log(this)`.

Comment: Even so, shouldnt it either print, Window or an error? And how can I print what the current context of this is in general whether it's the global or current object it's within? I'm just trying to understand where the rabbit hole goes.  Prototype and scope just alludes me.